# How to develop ASP.NET webpages with content varying with roles?

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, roles, personalization

I have an ASP.NET website for which I want to filter content based upon user Roles.
Say, for a "Manager" certain section displays and for an "Operations" guy, some other section is visible.
I don't want to use those `If-else blocks` in my UI throughout.
Is there any design guideline for separating my role based logic with my interface so that the controls automatically know when to be visible and when not? 
I am familiar with the sitemap based restrictions.
I am looking for some best practices followed for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

For web forms you could use multi views which display a certain view depending on the role.

For MVC you could use child actions. Happy to provide more info if you require it.

Comment: Do you mean using partial views for different roles?

Comment: Partials would still require you to use conditionals in your view logic. So are you using MVC or WebForms?

Comment: Well then I'd suggest Sitemap trimming as you mentioned OR handle the authentication in your controller method then full users to different actions based on their role.